# Is a function returning different number of elements depending on one input parameter considered bad practice?

Tags: python

I have a function that treats and returns data, but according to a boolean input parameter, should do a slightly different treatment (not different enough to justify a new function, I think). This slightly different treatment also requires the returning of an additional parameter.

Let's say I have this.

```
def func(data, special_case = False):
    #Do treatment
    ...

    if special_case:
        #do some more stuff
        ...

    #return results
    if special_case:
        return results, extra_results
    else:
        return results
```

Is that considered clean? Or maybe I should always return the second variable, but just make it empty when I'm not treating the special case?

```
    #return results
    if special_case:
        extra_results = something
    else:
        extra_results = []
    return results, extra_results
```

Comment: You could return `None` for the extra parameter in the basic function, that way you are always returning two things...

Comment: Returning a `collections.namedtuple` instance instead of an ordinary tuple is a nice way to allow callers that don't care about the extra value to ignore it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think so. Now your caller has to know about your function internals, specifically that your option changes the return type. That's just another thing for the caller to remember, and is poor encapsulation.

I would either split this into two functions (preferred), or return a `None` placeholder, or return an object that can be introspected for additional elements. But the structure of the returned data type should not change.

Comment: And to avoid code duplication, you can implement the "special case" signature as the main function with an optional flag to say "don't calculate extra value", then have a convenience function that sets that flag and also strips the redundant argument from the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should always return the same data type.

How about a dictionary, where one of the keys always contain a value and the second is either `None` or the special case value:

```
return { 'first_var':results, 
         'special_var': extra_results if extra_results else None}
```

Comment: "WORK IN PROGRESS" ??? What are you reserving your spot in line? Clever, though, if you fix it fast enough no one sees it because there are no edits.

Comment: For reference: I've written a `WORK IN PROGRESS` note at the bottom of my answer, after writing the general idea and before writing the code. Why the downvote? When I'm writing an answer (which takes about 2 minutes for a short one), often another user writes the almost exactly same answer. This way I give my general idea, so that other users won't waste their time writing the same solution.

Comment: Downvote because I view this as a strategy to have the first answer (your twice updated answer is good, however). Seems like poor etiquette, although that is a discussion for meta... If someone can post a complete answer before you, then they are not wasting their time.

Comment: Again, it prevents other users from writing the *exact same solution*. See meta discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86246/is-work-in-progress-note-a-bad-etiquette

Comment: (ping @Benjamin. Adam, see also [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) if you didn't know.)